# How To Host A Python Socket Server Online With My Personal Computer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am making a Online Multiplayer Chess Game, not to publish it online but just as a fun little quarantine project and to play with my friends. I've made it with sockets. You can get all the code for my project here: https://github.com/AgentTRIPLEX/Local-Multiplayer-Chess It really is quite a big one. The problem with me wanting to play with my friends across the city is that my program just allows connections on the local network per server. As I am just doing this for fun, I don't think spending money for this is wise. How do I host the server to gain connections from any internet connection from my personal computer?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is python-related, I'll have to change up the code if I'm going to accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using ngrok(https://ngrok.com/) it doesnt need port forwarding, download ngrok and run `ngrok.exe tcp 5001` 5001 is the port and tcp is the protocol(http, tcp, ..), to connect to it online use the "Forwarding" which will be something like 4.tcp.ngrok.io:4869 which will forward to localhost port 5001

NOTE: you can use it without an account but it will expire every 7 Hours, view the to use account read https://dashboard.ngrok.com/auth/your-authtoken (after creating an account)